# Create unique variables in sub classes using JavaScript polymorphism without overiding

Tags: javascript

I want to use `item.create()` in `projectModule`, `testCase` and businessFunction. because it's same prototype as `item`'s I copied the `item`'s to other functions. But i want have a one unique variable for these three functions which is called `itemType`. I tried this. But an exception is occurred. How can I place a unique variable for these three functions without overriding them?

Exception:

```
projectModule.create.prototype.itemType = 'module';
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

JavaScript Code

```
 var item = function () {};
    item.prototype.create = function (projectName, itemName) {
      console.log(projectName);
      console.log(itemName);
      console.log(itemType);
    };


/**
 * create module
 */
var projectModule = function () {};
projectModule.prototype = Object.create(item.prototype);
projectModule.create.prototype.itemType = 'module';

/**
 * create tc
 */
var testCase = function () {};
testCase.prototype = Object.create(item.prototype);
testCase.create.prototype.itemType = 'tc';


/**
 * create bc
 */
var businessComponent = function () {};
businessComponent.prototype = Object.create(item.prototype);
businessComponent.create.prototype.itemType = 'bc';
```

Comment: There should not be any `.create` in the `….prototype.itemType`?

Comment: Also the way you wrote it, `.itemType` will be a property of the instance (`this`, [see here about promise callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572)) not a variable in the scope of your `create` method

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have solved the error for me. Swapped .create and .prototype around.

```
var projectModule = function () {};

projectModule.prototype = Object.create(item.prototype);
projectModule.prototype.create.itemType = 'module';

/**
 * create tc
 */
var testCase = function () {};
testCase.prototype = Object.create(item.prototype);
testCase.prototype.create.itemType = 'tc';


/**
 * create bc
 */
var businessComponent = function () {};
businessComponent.prototype = Object.create(item.prototype);
businessComponent.prototype.create.itemType = 'bc';
```

Comment: so how can i use the variable?